# Rails.logger statements don't have fluent tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, fluentd

I'm trying to setup sending Rails logs to a collector via fluentd. I'm using the act-fluent-logger-rails, lograge and fluent-plugin-parser gems. When I navigate my site, GET and POST requests get matched, parsed, tagged and sent along to the collector correctly, but I can't get anything I log during a request via Rails.logger to be passed along by fluentd because the statements don't have a tag.

For example, in the rails console of the app:

`irb(main):003:0> logger.info("Test")`

results in the following in my td-agent.log:

`2016-05-23 20:01:45 +0000 [warn]: pattern not match with data 'Test'
 2016-05-23 20:01:45 +0000 fluent.warn: {"message":"pattern not match with data 'Test'"}`

The relevant configuration:

/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf

```
    <match tv.app>
      @type forward

      # primary host
      <server>
        host 10.0.0.0
        port 24224
      </server>

      flush_interval 60s
    </match>

    <match rails.app>
      @type parser
      key_name messages
      format json
      tag tv.app
    </match>
```

config/application.rb

```
config.logger = ActFluentLoggerRails::Logger.
            new(settings: {
               host: '127.0.0.1',
               port: 24224,
               tag: 'rails.app',
               messages_type: 'string'
            })
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue. Anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: Sorry. I'm no longer with the company I was with when working on this problem, and no longer am working with this type of setup, so I have no idea if anyones answers will be correct at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You have lograge formatter set to JSON, and your fluentd.conf also specifies JSON.
However, your code from the console is a string.

Have you tried

```
logger.info({:test => true}.to_json)
```